# VK API прерывистая работа

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Есть бот для группы вконтакте, он отправляет сообщение пользователям когда они выходят или входят в группу, а так же пара простых команд. 
Ситуация такая что бот работает 4 минуты, а потом 10 минут не отвечает и потом все повторяется(4 минуты работы, 10 минут ступора).
Это отследил в callback api во вкладке запросы, после 4 минут функционирования просто перестают там появляться(фиксироваться) запросы. 
Подскажите с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Знаю у VK API есть ограничения по количеству запросов в единицу времени. Точные цифры не помню. Возможно вас блокируют на какое-то время из-за частого использования. Но это лишь предположение

Answer (score 0):

Какая выдается ошибка в период простоя?

Если code 6, то слишком много запросов за единицу времени. Скорее всего у вас включается ограничение по частоте на количество сообщений.